# Persistent JSON Decode Error when Creating PayPal payment(testing) in Laravel Integration (json_decode error: Syntax error)

Tags: laravel

I'm working on integrating PayPal into my Laravel project for payments. I'm encountering a persistent JSON decode error while trying to create an order using the PayPal API. Despite reviewing the JSON structure and trying different solutions, I'm stuck with the error.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
public function paypalPayment(Request $request)
{
    // ... (initialize provider and set API credentials)

    $data = [
        "intent" => "CAPTURE",
        "application_context" => [
            "return_url" => route("paymentSuccess"),
            "cancel_url" => route("paymentCancel")
        ],
        "purchase_units" => [
            [
                "amount" => [
                    "currency_code" => "USD",
                    "value" => "100.00"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $response = $provider->createOrder($data);
    dd($response);
}
```

Thank you,
Aok Ponlork

I've cleared the cache, checked compatibility, and reviewed the JSON, but the error remains. Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.